# How to install and run pandas python library in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: numpy, python-3.x, pandas

I am using pydev plugin in Eclipse Juno for my python programming in windows 7 and i am using python 3.2, it works fine while running python application which using standard python packages. For my one of my project i have to use pandas library, for that i download and install numpy and pandas Windows installer for python 3. But while running even a small program it shows error message. So anyone have any idea about how to install and test pandas in Windows 7 by using eclipse, just pass it to me.

The error message is like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
import numpy
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .type_check import *
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
from numpy.testing import Tester
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from unittest import TestCase
File "C:\Python32\lib\unittest\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
from .case import (TestCase, FunctionTestCase, SkipTest, skip, skipIf,
File "C:\Python32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 6, in <module>
import pprint
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
```

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 1):

I think you have Install panda: here you can find panda package for windows here
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas#downloads